# An Application of law of large numbers.

Tags: probability-theory

Let {$X_k$} be a sequence of independent random variables with mean $\mu$ and finite variance . Define $S_n$ = $X_1 + X_2 +... +X_n$.

(i) Show that law of large numbers doesn't hold for sequence {$S_n$}

(ii)Show that law of large numbers applies for sequence {$a_k$$S_k$} if n$a_n$ -> o.

$Note$: This is a question from Discrete Probability theory by William Feller. I have tried solving it on my own but it seems my understanding is limited. Any ideas and suggestions on approaching similar kind of problems is greatly welcomed

Comment: Why has it been down voted? Is anything wrong?

Comment: If the first part, if $\mu\ne0$, then $S_n$ diverges.

Comment: Sorry. But can you show it mathematically? I was thinking something along that line but I couldn't come with a concrete answer

Comment: You should include a description of what exactly is giving you trouble. What have you tried, why didn't it work or where did you get stuck, etc. The downvote is probably because your question lacks this, and could be percieved as "do my homework for me".

Comment: Actually I have been trying to learn probability theory on my own and I am stuck trying to solve this question. Regarding your suggestion isn't ${S_n}/{n}$ convergent?

Comment: And isn't convergence of series a sufficient condition and not a necessary one

Comment: It was sequence not *series*

Comment: Sure, $\{S_N\}$ is a sequence. But since $S_n$ is defined as the sum of terms of the sequence $\{X_k\}$, it is a series.

Answer (score 1):

Note that this is informal demonstration. It might have mistakes that make it fail as a formal proof, but based on your comment about self-teaching, I get the impression that you just want to know the basic reasoning.

Let $\overline{X}_n$=$\dfrac{X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_n}{n}$ and $\mu=E[X]$. By the (strong) law of large numbers, $$P\left(\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\overline{X}_n=\mu\right)=1$$
This isn't quite the same as saying that as $n\rightarrow\infty$, $\overline{X}_n\rightarrow\mu$, because $P=1$ means that it is *almost sure* (or *almost certain*).

By the definition of $S_n$ and $\overline{X}_n$, we have $S_n=n\cdot\overline{X}_n$. So what is $\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}n\overline{X}_n$? Well, if $\overline{X}_n\not\rightarrow0$, then the limit diverges. Even if $\overline{X}_n$ converges to $0$, we cannot determine the value of the limit without knowing the rate of convergence of $\overline{X}_n$. We don't know this, and I'm pretty sure that since $X$ is a random variable, it isn't even defined. This means that *at best*, we can't determine the convergence of $\{S_n\}$, even probabilistically, and if $\mu\ne0$, then $\{S_n\}$ diverges.

You can also look at it like this: $E[X+Y]=E[X]+E[Y]$, which means that $E[S_n]=E[X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_n]=n\mu$. So if you wanted to show that
$$
P\left(\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}S_n=\nu\right)=1
$$
how would you choose $\nu$? You can't.

For the second part, we have already shown that $S_n=n\overline{X}_n$, so
$a_nS_n=na_n\overline{X}_n$.
Since we are given that $na_n\rightarrow0$ and we know that $\overline{X}_n\xrightarrow{a.s.}\mu$, then we can say that
$$
P\left(\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_nS_n=0\cdot\mu=0\right)=1
$$